# Does normalizing predictor variables help in case of dnn regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I am using tensorflow's **DNNRegressor**. Would like to know if normalizing (applying log or inverse transformation etc.) my numerical predictor variables would help in improving model performance and if so, what is the underlying logic? 
P.S. MSE is being used for training loss.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of normalizing, for example you could use Batch Normalization layers, which normalizes the outputs of a layer using a Gaussian distribution.

In terms of prediction, it makes no difference. The neural network can easily counter your normalization since it just scales the weights and changes the bias. The big problem is in the training. Usually inputs are normalizes to keep values low and help avoding a problem called [exploding gradient](https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks/). This happends due to traditional backpropagation with sigmoid activation functions, that can saturate the sigmoid derivative.

The answer to [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/how-to-normalize-data-for-neural-network-and-decision-forest) does a good explanation to why it is important.

Answer (score 0):

It sure does. DNNRegressor is a neural network, and you use gradient descent to optimize this (maybe some advanced stuff like Adam, but in the end it's still SGD). And you have to normalize your features to get better gradients. By better, I mean more or less equal, not extremely large and not extremely small. And by normalize I mean:

- Features should have 0 mean
- Features should have the same deviation (1 is a usual choice here)
- It should be distributed normal-ish. Uniform is fine, normal is fine, lognormal is questionable, exponential is dangerous. The idea is: outliers will harm your performance.

There are a lot of great resources on how to make SGD work better, but I would suggest taking a look at [Hinton's lecture](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf) and [this cool review of gradient descent algorithms](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/).

Comment: Just to confirm, do you mean normalization would work only if i am using SGD and not otherwise? Actually I am not using batching as of now in my current approach, so my 1 step spans over the entire data, i.e. 1 step = 1 epoch in my case.

Comment: Oh, okay. No, you still need to normalize data. The key here is that you are using gradients, stochasticity is not that important after all. 0-mean/1-deviation is crucial while normalizing the shape of the distribution is secondary (yet it usually helps)